# Android - checkBox always sending true to a different activity

Tags: java, android

I have manually created a Preferences Activity, where the checkbox data will be sent to a different Activity. When I send it, it is right. But when I receive it, I need to know if it is true or false, and I always get false.

Here's my code to send:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(checkBox.isChecked())
        {
            String trueThumb_check = "checked_thumb";
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("trueThumbnail", trueThumb_check);
            Toast.makeText(Preferences.this, "check prefs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(i);
            killAc();
        }
        else
        {
            String falseThumb_check = "not_check_thumb";
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("trueThumbnail", falseThumb_check);
            Toast.makeText(Preferences.this, "not check prefs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(i);
            killAc();
        }

    }
```

And to receive:

```
try {
            SharedPreferences thumb_check = this.getSharedPreferences(
              "ch4an.ytheloader", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            //To read preferences
            String thumb_thumb = thumb_check.getString("trueThumbnail", "checked_thumb");

            if (thumb_thumb.contains("checked_thumb")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "checkBox ativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }  if(thumb_thumb.contains("not_checked_thumb")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "checkBox não ativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = thumb_check.edit();
            editor.apply();

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Null checkBox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

I believe the problem might be here:

```
String thumb_thumb = thumb_check.getString("trueThumbnail", "checked_thumb");
```

I always get a single **" checked_thumb"**, but I don't know how to get **"thumb_thumb"** for both.
I've tried sending different *keys* and *values* (because both are under the "trueThumbnail" key) but I still get true only.

Comment: Write your question in english

Comment: Stackoverflow is in english

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Sorry. I am new here. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your receiving code is wrong. When you're sending the data you're sending through a intent, there's nothing wrong in there but when you're trying to receive you are getting from the SharedPreferences

So to access the data instead of this

```
SharedPreferences thumb_check = this.getSharedPreferences(
              "ch4an.ytheloader", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It should be this

```
Intent thumb_check = getIntent();
String thumb_thumb = thumb_check.getStringExtra("trueThumbnail", "checked_thumb");
```

A rewrite of the receive code

```
    try {
    // Get the intent passed through activities
    Intent thumb_check = getIntent();
    // Get the string in the extra
    String intent_Thumb = thumb_check.getStringExtra("trueThumbnail", "checked_thumb");

    // Get the shared preferences
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                          "ch4an.ytheloader", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    
    //To read from preferences
        String pref_Thumb = prefs("trueThumbnail", "checked_thumb");
    
    // preform what ever you want
    
} catch (Throwable e) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Null checkBox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You're mixing the SharedPreferences and Intents and it seems that you are lost in that code
Make sure you read the android documentation it helps a lot.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

**EDIT** Responding your comment

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("ch4an.ytheloader", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("trueThumbnail", intent_Thumb);
// Or if you want to put a bool assuming that you have a
// variable called intent_Thumb_as_boolean as a boolean
editor.putBoolean("trueThumbnail", intent_Thumb_as_boolean);
editor.commit();
```

Check the android docs for the SharedPreferences

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Thank you very much. The values ​​were distributed separately. How do I save the result?